# Python Docx Carriage Return

Tags: python, python-docx

`Python Docx` is a pretty good library for generating Microsoft Word documents for something that doesn't directly deal with all of the COM stuff. Nonetheless, I'm running into some limitations.

- Does anyone have any idea how one would put a carriage return in a string of text?

I want a paragraph to have multiple lines without there being extra space between them. However, writing out a string that separates the lines with the usual `\n` is not working. Nor is using `&#10` or `&#13`. Any other thoughts, or is this framework too limited for something like that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is possible. It looks as though Word is in fact treating presses of the enter key (I am treating this action as a sort of programmatic equivalent of "\r\n" and "\n") as the creation of a new paragraph.

---

If I record a macro in Word that consists of:

1. Typing the text "One"
2. Pressing the enter key

I get VBA of:

```
Selection.TypeText Text:="One"
Selection.TypeParagraph
```

---

If I create a Word document that looks like this (pressing enter after each word):

```
One

Two

Three
```

The body of that document looks like this in the `documents.xml` file:

```
<w:body>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00BE37B0" w:rsidRDefault="00CF2350">
        <w:r>
            <w:t>One</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00CF2350" w:rsidRDefault="00CF2350">
        <w:r>
            <w:t>Two</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00CF2350" w:rsidRDefault="00CF2350">
        <w:r>
            <w:t>Three</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:sectPr w:rsidR="00CF2350" w:rsidSect="001077CC">
        <w:pgSz w:w="11906" w:h="16838"/>
        <w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1440" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1440" w:header="708" w:footer="708" w:gutter="0"/>
        <w:cols w:space="708"/>
        <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/>
    </w:sectPr>
</w:body>
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.paragraph%28v=office.14%29.aspx) we can see that the `<w:p>` element represents a paragraph.

---

I think the solution to this would be to follow the example in [Python Docx](https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx/blob/master/example-makedocument.py):

```
body.append(paragraph("Hi."))
body.append(paragraph("My name is Alice."))
body.append(paragraph("Let's code"))
```

Or:

```
for paragraph_text in "Hi. \nMy name is Alice.\n Let's code".split("\n"):
    body.append(paragraph(paragraph_text.strip()))
```

**Edit:**

Looking into this some more, if you press Shift + Enter in Word it adds a manual line break (not a paragraph) via appending `Chr(11)`. In Open XML, this translates to a [Break](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.break%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Looking at the `docx.py` file of Python Docx, something like this might be the way to go (disclaimer: not tested):

```
for text in "Hi. \nMy name is Alice.\n Let's code".split("\n"):
    run = makeelement('r')
    run.append(makeelement('t', tagtext=text))
    run.append(makeelement('br'))
    body.append(run)
```

Comment: Your analysis of how the paragraphs are created looks right, but body.append(paragraph) doesn't appear to be a solution. That just recreates the problem you showed above with the "One", "Two", and "Three" paragraphs. What I want is something that somehow gets rid of that extra space between paragraphs, probably by somehow having a paragraph element recognize a single line break character.

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve your carriage return using python-docx by calling `add_break()` on your run.  For example:

```
doc = Document()
p = doc.add_paragraph()
run = p.add_run()
run.add_break()
```

[python-docx reference](http://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dev/analysis/features/text/breaks.html#candidate-protocol-run-add-break)

Answer (score 1):

As of v0.7.2, python-docx translates '\n' and '\r' characters in a string to `<w:br/>` elements, which provides the behavior you describe. It also translates '\t' characters into `<w:tab/>` elements.

This behavior is available for strings provided to:

- `Document.add_paragraph()`
- `Paragraph.add_run()`

and for strings assigned to:

- `Paragraph.text`
- `Run.text`